# Not able to execute two @Test in pageFactory

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, page-factory

<-Here is the base BaseClass which is extends by VerifyLoginTest & this will open driver->

```
public class BaseClass {
    private static Properties prop;
    protected static WebDriver driver;
    protected static WebDriverWait wait;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void propReading() {
        try {
            File file = new File(ConstantPaths.PROP_PATH);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(fileInputStream);
        } catch (
                IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Properties file not found");
        }
    }

    public static void initializeBrowser() //Selenium 4.6.0 after that
    {
        switch (prop.getProperty("browserName").toUpperCase()) {
            case "CHROME":
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                //options.addArguments("kiosk-printing");
                break;
            case "FIREFOX":
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                break;
            case "EDGE":
                driver = new EdgeDriver();
            default:
                System.out.println("Illegal Browser Name");
                break;
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("urlName"));
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    }

    public static void closeBrowser() {
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

While running same @test in pageFactory model it is giving invalidSessionId exception

```
package testscripts;//import java.util.*;

import actions.Actions;
import base.BaseClass;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import pagesobjects.HomePage;


public class VerifyLoginTest extends BaseClass{

    @BeforeMethod
    public void startBrowser()
    {
        BaseClass.initializeBrowser();
    }
    @Test
    public void verifyNoValue(){
        HomePage homePage = HomePage.getHomePageObj();
        homePage.enterInvestmentAmount("  ");
        homePage.clickOnCalculate();
        Assert.assertEquals(homePage.getErrorMsg(),"This field is required");
        Actions.takeScreenshot("verifyNoValue");
    }
    @Test
    public void verifyMinValue(){
        HomePage homePage = HomePage.getHomePageObj();
        homePage.enterInvestmentAmount("499");
        homePage.clickOnCalculate();
        Assert.assertEquals(homePage.getErrorMsg(),"Min Amount is 500");
        Actions.takeScreenshot("verifyMinValue");
    }
    @Test
    public void verifyMaxValue(){
        HomePage homePage = HomePage.getHomePageObj();
        homePage.enterInvestmentAmount("50000001");
        homePage.clickOnCalculate();
        Assert.assertEquals(homePage.getErrorMsg(),"Min Amount is 500");
        Actions.takeScreenshot("verifyMinValue");
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(){
        BaseClass.closeBrowser();
    }

}
```

This @Test are running in one browser instance only, I am expecting it to run on different browser as I have added 3 test annotation with before method

Comment: Did you try executing tests/methods in parallel from testng.xml? If you are planning to run each test in a different browser parallelly, then it should be defined at **Test** level or in testng.xml. Adding a @BeforeMethod doesn't execute tests in parallel mode.

Comment: Post your 'BaseClass.java' code and 'testng.xml'.

Comment: Thankyou for yout support @SrinivasuKaki, problem I was using sinlgeton design pattern in Pages layer & that initializing the elements only once hence it was executing commands in same browser instance.